# why I cannot open fileinfo extension in php

Tags: php, wampserver

I have modified in php.ini, and restart the apache server, I use wampserver.

[image]

but I use `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());`，I cannot see fileinfo in the output, why?

Comment: Use `phpinfo ()` and ensure the correct php.ini file is being updated/loaded

Comment: it has been updated ...

Comment: You are running this test using the browser and apache and not using the PHP CLI right?

Comment: maybe it is, so do you have any idea?